# css - img maxed with not working

Tags: html, css

I've been using css for a little bit now. I tried this code, but the div with the id "backInvis" is a image.

```css
#PageOne {
background-color: #230f2e;
}
#PageTwo {
    background-color: #2e0f29;
}
#PageThree {
    background-color: #140f2e;
}
#backInvis {
    z-index: -5;
    opacity: 0.75;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff6600;
}
```

```html
<div id="PageOne">
<div id="backInvi">.</div>
</div>

<div id="PageTwo">
<div id="backInvi">.</div>
</div>

<div id="PageThree">
<div id="backInvi">.</div>
</div>
```

Now I know that it is a issue to make a div a certain height without a element in it (if someone can help me with that that would be a nice cherry on top). But when I put a image, the width is often larger than my window. When I remove the (width: 100%;) I get the same image. What is the issue.

Comment: It would help to see the actual code.  Why are you saying that #backInvi is an image yet in the code its a div?  That doesn't make sense.  Can't help with what we cannot see.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to attempt to answer this without fully understanding where you are going with this code.

If you are referring to the following

```
<div id="backInvi"><img src="images/whatever.jpg"></div>
```

Then your css needs to be the following...

```
#backInvis {
    z-index: -5;
    opacity: 0.75;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff6600;
}

#backInvis img { float: left; width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

If that isn't what you are trying to do, please clarify and update code to what you actually want it to be.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?  If so, please accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question you've asked doesn't make any sense at all. <div> tags are used to create a division or a section in html. They don't have any predefined properties like margin, padding, font-size and border at all. It must be defined using css selectors. An image inside a division tag will auto adjust itself according to some factors until you define the width and height properties. If you define a div tag with a certain width, then image will not try to come out of the division box. If it still you can use overflow in css...

```
div{
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 60%;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also going to attempt to answer this without fully understanding where you are going with this code.

```css
/* Use this css */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#PageOne {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #230f2e;
}

#PageOne .backInvis {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fa45ed;
}

#PageTwo {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  background-color: #2e0f29;
}

#PageTwo .backInvis {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fa45ed;
}

#PageThree {
  position: relative;
  top: 36px;
  background-color: #140f2e;
}

#PageThree .backInvis {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fa45ed;
}
```

```html
<!-- Use this Html -->


<div id="PageOne">
  <div class="backInvis">.</div>
</div>

<div id="PageTwo">
  <div class="backInvis">.</div>
</div>

<div id="PageThree">
  <div class="backInvis">.</div>
</div>
```

First thing u never use same id more than once in the same page.....

If that isn't what you are trying to do, please clarify and update code to what you actually want it to be.